# Getting Java Security Exception with java comm api from GWT

Tags: api, security, gwt, serial-port, x10

Im developing a GWT application to control an X10 home automation controller(USB Device).
It uses the java Comm APi to communicate witht the controller. But im getting this exception when trying to call the comm api remotly.

```
Initializing AppEngine server
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
javax.comm:  Error loading javax.comm.properties!
access denied (java.io.FilePermission /home/user/Project-Source/HAMS/src read)

java.io.IOException: javax.comm: platform driver class name = null
                     (Check 'driver' property in javax.comm.properties)

 at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.loadDriver(CommPortIdentifier.java:244)
 at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:109)
 at x10.CM11ASerialController.<init>(CM11ASerialController.java:113)
 at com.core.hams.server.x10.X10ControllerImpl.<init>(X10ControllerImpl.java:44)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:121)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:352)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:844)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:396)
 at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
22-Feb-2010 14:25:20 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in javax.servlet.ServletException: init:
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at x10.CM11ASerialController.<init>(CM11ASerialController.java:113)
 at com.core.hams.server.x10.X10ControllerImpl.<init>(X10ControllerImpl.java:44)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:121)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:352)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:844)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:396)
 at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name can't be null
 at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:171)
 at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:249)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkDelete(SecurityManager.java:990)
 at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:131)
 ... 35 more
22-Feb-2010 14:25:20 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
java.lang.NullPointerException: name can't be null
 at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:171)
 at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:249)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkDelete(SecurityManager.java:990)
 at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:131)
 at x10.CM11ASerialController.<init>(CM11ASerialController.java:113)
 at com.core.hams.server.x10.X10ControllerImpl.<init>(X10ControllerImpl.java:44)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:121)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:352)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:844)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:396)
 at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
22-Feb-2010 14:25:20 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /hams/x10controller
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at x10.CM11ASerialController.<init>(CM11ASerialController.java:113)
 at com.core.hams.server.x10.X10ControllerImpl.<init>(X10ControllerImpl.java:44)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:121)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:352)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:844)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:396)
 at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name can't be null
 at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:171)
 at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:249)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkDelete(SecurityManager.java:990)
 at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:131)
 ... 35 more
22-Feb-2010 14:25:20 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
java.lang.NullPointerException: name can't be null
 at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:171)
 at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:249)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkDelete(SecurityManager.java:990)
 at javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier.<clinit>(CommPortIdentifier.java:131)
 at x10.CM11ASerialController.<init>(CM11ASerialController.java:113)
 at com.core.hams.server.x10.X10ControllerImpl.<init>(X10ControllerImpl.java:44)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093)
 at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:51)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:121)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:712)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
 at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
 at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:352)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:139)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:313)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:506)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:844)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
 at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:381)
 at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:396)
 at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:442)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check for permission on this directory

access denied (java.io.FilePermission /home/user/Project-Source/HAMS/src read)